# Crop image from django template

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to crop an image from django template? I am not saving the image anywhere it is  URL [example](http://example.com/iamges/sample.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Check this: http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#template-examples

Answer (score 0):

Or check http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/versions.html#image-versions